# PM2 not making clusters

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

I just installed pm2, I already has done clustering in my app.js using node cluster module.

When I use pm2 start app.js -i 4  to start my app.js it only show me one online instance. It should show me 4 instance Please tell me what is the problem

[Screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZEcD.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run this command...

it should work.

`pm2 stop all`

`pm2 delete all`

`pm2 start app.js -i 2`

where `i` is the number of `instance` you want to start.

Always use `pm2 delete all` to unregister the `CPU`, since if you stop it, it still reserve the `CPU`

Comment: why we have to use delete all ?

Comment: if you stop a process with `pm2` it still reserves one `CPU` for it even if it's not running. To free the `CPU` need to run `pm2 delete all`